# smallest possible sum of the values of subarrays

Tags: java

I'm trying to understand question and solving it using java.

But first I'm not able to understand properly.

Here is the question:

You are given an array a of length n and an integer c.

The value of some array b of length k is the sum of its elements except for the  smallest. For example, the value of the array [3, 1, 6, 5, 2] with c = 2 is 3 + 6 + 5 = 14.

Among all possible partitions of a into contiguous subarrays output the smallest possible sum of the values of these subarrays.

```
Input
The first line contains integers n and c (1 ≤ n, c ≤ 100 000).

The second line contains n integers ai (1 ≤ ai ≤ 109) — elements of a.

Output
Output a single integer  — the smallest possible sum of values of these subarrays of some partition of a.


Examples
inputCopy
3 5
1 2 3
output
6
inputCopy
12 10
1 1 10 10 10 10 10 10 9 10 10 10
output
92
inputCopy
7 2
2 3 6 4 5 7 1
output
17
inputCopy
8 4
1 3 4 5 5 3 4 1
output
23
```

In the third example one of the optimal partitions is [2, 3], [6, 4, 5, 7], [1] with the values 3, 13 and 1 respectively.

My Understanding:

1) Partition is being being done within continuous numbers. Correct ?

2) What is the significance of Integer c in input ?

3) How is being done in third example ? I mean after having subarrays, How 13 came out from second subarray ?

Can anyone help me to understand the question ? I can write code myself.

Comment: I recommend taking a look at kadanes algorithm. (Solution to max sum subarray) and seeing if you can adapt it to for the min solution.

Comment: @giorgiga, Its taken from here ..http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/940/E

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming but simply understanding a problem statement.

Comment: @KevinWelker IMHO the question is ok: most of programming is understanding problems

Comment: @giorgiga But there is no issue that will be of technical value to future users of this site.  The question is wholly specific to understanding words on a problem, nor about providing a technical solution. I.e., it is tagged as a Java question, but any valid answer has nothing to do with Java.